# how to remove <return> tag from Axis2 web service response in JSON or XML?

Tags: java, json

I created a web service which uses the Axis2 framework. I noticed that the response generated for the web service always includes the return tag.so, how to remove the return tag from web service response?    I just want the plain XML/JSON response...
            Ex.
               
                  
                       1
                       Sumit

```
         I need response like,-

             <Student>
                   <rollNo>1</rollNo>
                   <studentNm>Sumit</studentNm>
             </Student>
```

Comment: please, if possible provide us with additional info (code and configuration)

Answer (score 0):

You probably aren't able to remove the headers from the response object of the web service. Usually return values are wrapped in a return object. Why don't you just add that "return" to the path you are getting or grab a sub section?